# Set the company name - itunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I recently added a new app to itunes connect (haven't uploaded yet) and as I saw in few videos and tutorials I should be able to set the company name once I'm trying to add the app. This option simply haven't be offered to me. How can I set the company name now? Was there any change in the apple developers tools?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue. First time trying to add the app to my personal account, and there isn't a company name field. I'm an individual developer, so I'm not sure why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible anymore to set a company name when using Personal Developer Program. I've search on apple developers forum and found this:

> ...For a personal account, your developer name on the store is always
>   your name. (It didn't used to be, in the early days of the app store,
>   but it is now.) For a company account, it's always the legal name of
>   your company...

What a pitty!

link: https://devforums.apple.com/message/907715#907715

Answer (score 0):

It's never been possible to add a company name for a **personal** user account.
In case your account is a **company account**, then, **the first time you create an app**, iTunes Connect lets you choose the company name that will be displayed forever more.
You may found the documentation from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/2_BeforeYouBegin/BeforeYouBegin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH11-SW15), at the end of the page (*Setting Your Company Name* section).

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Comment: Ok. I will look for it again. Thanks